# Chrome CSS injection suddenly not working

Tags: google-chrome, sass

I use DevTools for in-browser editing of my SCSS. I have the workspace setup, files mapped, sourcemaps generated, and grunt compiling any changes to my .scss files.

For the last year Chrome has successfully injected any changes to my css files into the local site I'm working on. However just recently this stopped working for all of my sites. The css file is still compiled when I make changes from Chrome, but the changes are not injected.

Any ideas on why?

Comment: Without knowing which tool you use for injecting CSS there's no way for anyone to even guess what might be wrong.

Comment: @NilsKaspersson - There is no tool. Chrome has a built-in function that (normally) watches changes in the workspace files and injects changes.

Comment: I think I have the same problem. Up to 2 weeks ago I had the scss editing working from within the styles inspector, and now (even though the mappings are correct) my edits are not persisted in the filesystem. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @RamiroAraujo - Unfortunately not. I have 3 coding projects that I use with Chrome SASS, and now 2 of 3 are broken.

Comment: @jetlej 2 of 3? how are the mappings set on the one it's working? I _made_ it kinda work, by mapping individual css to scss, but only work as long each scss's css is included in the html by itself, does not work for example with a main scss importing partials, since the moment I edit the "partial" in the inspector, all the generated css is mangled inside the main scss. I know for my own experience this WORKED, I'm losing my mind here :'(

Comment: @RamiroAraujo - I have no idea, they all use the same Grunt file structure, Bootstrap, etc. They just keep dropping off randomly.

Answer (score 0):

In the developer tools settings (click the cog at the top-right), you should see an "Auto-reload generated CSS" option. Is that ticked?

[image]

Comment: That was already enabled. It worked as expected before a few weeks ago, so I'm sure the settings are correct.