# Chrome Devtools Workspace no longer works with Sass live updating

Tags: sass, google-chrome-devtools, workspace, osx-elcapitan

I had been using Chrome Devtools, Workspace, and Sass for live updating my scss files without problem since Chrome v46. With Chrome v47 it doesn't seem to work. It could also have something to do with permissions and how Mac El Capitan handles security now in regards to the Sass gem, but I'm no expert.

Basically, I'm just watching Sass changes from the Terminal. I have my Workspace directory added in Devtools, local Sass file set up to the network Sass file. When I make changes to the scss file inside Devtools, upon save, my local scss file updates in Sublime Text, so I see it is working, but the local web page is never updated to reflect said changes.

Seems like someone else encounter a similar issue before: [Chrome CSS injection suddenly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739312/chrome-css-injection-suddenly-not-working/34659311)

[image: Chrome Devtools with Sass]

Comment: Issue being discussed at Chromium. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=273384